# Unable to import DMP file that is made in 11g2 to Oracle 18c

Tags: oracle, centos, impdp, expdp, oracle-18c

My OS=CENTOS 7
Oracle=18c XE

I am trying to import a DMP file that is exported from XE 11g2 and now trying to import it in 18c XE. 
Here are the errors:

```
[root@linux gsw]# impdp user/pass remap_tablespace=SYSTEM:myUserName remap_tablespace=USERS:myUserName dumpfile=myUserName.dmp directory=myUserName

Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Jun 4 01:09:34 2020
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31633: unable to create master table "myUserName.SYS_IMPORT_FULL_05"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1142
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1035
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1023
```

What I did is:

```
create TABLESPACE myUserName
DATAFILE '/opt/oracle/oradata/XE/myUserName01.dbf' SIZE 10M
AUTOEXTEND ON
NEXT 512K
MAXSIZE 250M;

ALTER DATABASE 
DATAFILE '/opt/oracle/oradata/XE/myUserName01.dbf'
AUTOEXTEND ON
MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;

SQL> ALTER USER myUserName quota unlimited on myUserName;

User altered.

SQL> create user myUserName identified by pass;

User created.

SQL> grant connect, resource to myUserName;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant read, write on directory myUserName to myUserName;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create database link to myUserName;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create table to myUserName;

Grant succeeded.
```

**UPDATE-1**

```
SQL> GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO myUserName;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO myUserName;

Grant succeeded.
```

Now the errors changed as:

```
Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Jun 4 01:39:50 2020
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-39143: dump file "/opt/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump/myUserName/myUserName_110516.dmp" may be an original export dump file
```

Best Regards

Comment: Did you create it on the CDB or the PDB? Are you importing into the PDB?

Comment: I have exported as `expdp myUserName/myUserName DIRECTORY=myUserName DUMPFILE=myUserName.dmp logfile=myUserName.log SCHEMAS=myUserName`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the impdp command:

```
VERSION=11.2.0
```

Comment: Please expand on this answer - references and quotes from websites for example!

Comment: @pmdba VERSION=11.2.0 not works `impdp user/pass remap_tablespace=SYSTEM:USER remap_tablespace=USERS:USER dumpfile=file_110516.dmp directory=user VERSION=11.2.0` same error throwing as I written in my **UPDATE-1** part of my question

Answer (score 0):

Problem #1: Trying to stored objects into a tablespace on which your have no **quota**.

While you created a tablespace for your account, you did not make that the *default tablespace* for your user so, when creating objects without an explicit tablespace clause, it would have tried to put them into a [wrong] tablespace on which the account had no quota.  Boom!

Problem #2: bad dump file specification

You cannot specify the full path to the dump file, as we once did with **imp**.

Instead you use a [database] **Directory** object and place the dump file into the [file system] directory referenced by that Directory:

```
SQL> create or replace directory MY_DIR 
     as '/opt/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump/myUserName' ; 

SQL> grant read, write on directory MY_DIR to myUserName ; 

$ impdp user/pass \
    directory=MY_DIR \
    dumpfile=myUserName.dmp \
    remap_tablespace=SYSTEM:myUserName \
    remap_tablespace=USERS:myUserName \
```

I would suggest that "borrowing" objects from the SYSTEM tablespace is Bad Idea.
I do not see why you would *ever* want to do this.

If you're going to be doing this on a regular basis, I would strongly recommend you look into **Wallets** for storing credentials, rather than specifying on the command-line.

Comment: Phill W. this is output of your recommendations `Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

UDI-01017: operation generated ORACLE error 1017
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Username: system/password

Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-39143: dump file "/opt/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump/gsw/gsw_110516.dmp" may be an original export dump file`

Comment: "ORA-39143: dump file "/opt/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump/gsw/gsw_110516.dmp" may be an original export dump file"
Was the file created by expdp or by the original exp (which won't work).

Comment: W. Its working when I use `imp` with one warning

Comment: Then you need to use *expdp* to create another dump file.  The one that you have, created by *imp*, will not work with impdp.